# About self => in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm looking at the "Explicitly Typed Self References" [discussion](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/124). The example starts like this.

```
abstract class Graph {
  type Edge
  type Node <: NodeIntf
  abstract class NodeIntf {
    def connectWith(node: Node): Edge
  }
  def nodes: List[Node]
  def edges: List[Edge]
  def addNode: Node
}
```

The example runs into trouble (which the `self` construct is introduced to fix) when it attempts to declare a subclass of `Graph`.

```
abstract class DirectedGraph extends Graph {
  ...
  class NodeImpl extends NodeIntf {
    def connectWith(node: Node): Edge = {
      val edge = newEdge(this, node)
      edges = edge :: edges
      edge
    }
  }
  protected def newEdge(from: Node, to: Node): Edge
  ...
}
```

The problem is that the function `newEdge` expects a `Node` as its first argument but gets a `NodeImpl` in the call to it inside `connectWith`.

Why is this not a self-inflicted problem? Wouldn't be easily solved by declaring `Node` an **abstract class** or a **trait** to begin with rather than a subtype of `NodeIntf`? If that had been done `NodeImpl` could be a subclass of `Node` and all would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes and no.

Yes, if you own all the code, you could design the hierarchy better to spare yourself needless complexity.

But you assume that you designed `Graph`. What if you didn't? Maybe the class comes from a library or legacy code you can't change, but you still wish to utilize it.

The example may be a bit contrived, but it is meant to demonstrate how explicitly typing `this` can solve a certain class of problems.

Comment: Thanks--although in that case the problem arises because <code>Node</code> is declared to be any subclass of <code>NodeIntf</code> and then required as the first argument to <code>newEdge</code>. It would make more sense to make the first argument to <code>newEdge</code> of type <code>NodeIntf</code>. After all what does it mean to say that something must be of *any* class that is a subclass of some class C but not of type C itself?

Answer (score 0):

Example what you show is about Family Polymorphism and it is a **study case**.

Problem solved by define type variable `Node`.

```
abstract class DirectedGraph extends Graph {
  ...
  type Node = NodeImp

  class NodeImpl extends NodeIntf {
  ...
```

Anther solution is define self-type:

```
class NodeImpl extends NodeIntf {
    self: Node =>
```

And your solution is:

```
trait Edge
```

All solution is acceptable.

I think you refer to article [M.Odersky @ 2006](https://www.google.com.ua/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=Gux_UpSTEemH4ASry4CADQ&url=http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaOverview.pdf&cd=3&ved=0CDQQFjAC&usg=AFQjCNH3ppOK0iXj1sUhwvWLmaEkTAJK0A&sig2=64SwWGs5nu8fRwZVswWfcg) and it little bit confusing because mix many concepts: type variable with embedded polymorphism, family polymorphism and self typing.

Imho idea of this article to show set of variance possible solutions.